# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float' comparing two dataframes

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, dataframe

Suppose there are two dataframes - `DF1` and `DF2`. 
`DF1` comes from .txt comma delimited file using `pandas.read_csv(path/to/file, header=1, index_col=[0])` and `DF2` comes from .xlsx file using `pandas.read_excel(path/to/file, header=0, index_col=[1])`. `'header=1'` from file1 contains same column names as `header=0` in file2 and `index_col=[0]` contains same object names as `index_col=[1]`.
My aim is to subtract values of each column for each object (raw). I am trying to do following:

`diff = df1 - df2`

or

`diff = pd.DataFrame.sub(df1,df2)`

But it always shows mentioned error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it is what it said, some cells contain string then minus with float.
Could you provide example of your df

Comment: Just print every cell before if statement. You will see the trouble line. Then check if it's float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very likely, one of your DataFrames contains strings, and the other one numbers.

For example, if I write

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['3', '2', '6'])
df1 - df2
```

then I get

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
```

To fix it, I could add the line

```
df2 = df2.astype(int)
```

and then, the subtraction will work.

Comment: Happy to help! Note that, for your specific example, you might want to use `astype(float)`